# PHP Truncates Multi-Word $_POST variable

Tags: php, html, post

When I do the following line with $gamename=Cactus Canyon

```
echo <a href=submitascore.php?gamename=$gamename>$gamename</a><br/>;
```

The result is this:

```
http://submitascore.php?gamename=Cactus
```

Such that the word ' Canyon' is lost.

I'm guessing it has something to do with single and/or double quotes, but I've not been able to put together the right combination.  Can you help?

Thank you!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Answer (score 1):

Oh just add double quotes? This works fine.

```
$gamename = "Cactus";

echo "<a href=submitascore.php?gamename=$gamename>$gamename</a><br/>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
echo <a href=submitascore.php?gamename=$gamename>$gamename</a><br/>;
```

To this:

```
echo "<a href=submitascore.php?gamename=".urlencode($gamename).">$gamename</a><br/>";
```

That did the trick!  Thank you